# change pixel color when moving the image

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiimageview, uiimage

I have two images(img1 and img2). The first one is fixed and the second one is draggable.
img1 has a black contour and the rest of pixels is white.

[image: Example image]

When I move img2, it can intersect the first one. And here I should change pixels of the non intersected part.
So first of all, I use a method to get Pixels at specific points.
Then,I create two methods to get  points coordinates of  the two images frames and save them into two tables.
The purpose of those two methods is to compare points coordinates of the two images when dragging img2.
I mean when I move img2 I pick a location which is a point and I compare it the to all the points that img1 contains. If this point is not included into the img1, I change its pixel color.
After that, I compare betweeen the two tables and I get the points non common and change its color pixel. I really struggled with that. Here the snippet of my code :

```
-(NSMutableArray *) getPixelColorAtLocation:(CGPoint)point
{
    unsigned char pixel[4] = {0};
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -point.x, -point.y);

    [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",pixel[0]]];
    [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",pixel[1]]];
    [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",pixel[2]]];
    [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",pixel[3]]];
    return array;
}
-(NSMutableArray *)getimg1Coordinate:(CGPoint)point{

    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *coordinates = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    int c,b;

    for ( c=v.frame.origin.x;c <v.frame.origin.x+v.frame.size.width;c++)
    {
        for(b = v.frame.origin.y ;b<v.frame.origin.y+v.frame.size.height;b++)
        {


            array =[self getPixelColorAtLocation:point];
            int red = [ [array objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
            int green = [ [array objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
            int blue = [ [array objectAtIndex:2] intValue];
            int alpha = [ [array objectAtIndex:3] intValue];

            if( red ==255)
            {
                if( green == 255)
                {
                    if( blue ==255)
                    {
                        if (alpha == 255)
                        {
                            [coordinates addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",point.x]];
                            [coordinates addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",point.y]];
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
return coordinates;
}


-(NSMutableArray *)getImgCoordinate :(CGPoint)point{

    NSMutableArray *coordinates = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    int c,b;

    for ( c=imgView.frame.origin.x;c <imgView.frame.origin.x+imgView.frame.size.width;c++)
    {
        for(b = imgView.frame.origin.y ;b<imgView.frame.origin.y+imgView.frame.size.height;b++)
        {

            [coordinates addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",point.x]];
            [coordinates addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",point.y]];
        }
    }
 return coordinates;
}
```

I create the two methods above to stock all the points coordinates in order to get the non common values.

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location  = [touch locationInView:[self view]];
    // move the image view
    [imgView setCenter:location];
    NSMutableArray *coordImg1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *coordImg2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    coordImg1 = [self getImg1Coordinate:location];
    coordImg2 = [ self getImg2Coordinate:location];

    for (id obj in coordImg) {//each obj in arr2


        if ([coordBubble containsObject:obj])
        {//if arr1 has the same obj(which is from arr2)

        }
        else {
            [self changePixels];

        }

    }
```

And here I get the problem how can I get only the pixels that I should change.
I am not sure what I am doing is the best way to get finally what I need.

```
- (void)changePixels    {
     CGImageRef imageRef = [img CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *rawData = malloc(height * width * 4);
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst| kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
     float red = 0.0,green = 0.0,blue = 0.0,alpha = 0.0;
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    for(int xx = 0; xx<width; xx++) {
        for(int yy = 0; yy<height; yy++) {
            int byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * yy) + xx * bytesPerPixel;

            red = rawData[byteIndex];
            green = rawData[byteIndex + 1];
            blue = rawData[byteIndex + 2];
            alpha = rawData[byteIndex + 3];

            if( alpha ==255.000000)
            {
                rawData[byteIndex] = 20;
                rawData[byteIndex+1] = green;
                rawData[byteIndex+2] =  140;
                rawData[byteIndex+3] = 60;
            }

        }
    }

CGContextRef contextref = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,   bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
   UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGBitmapContextCreateImage(contextref)];
    CGContextDrawImage(contextref, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    UIImageView *imgV= [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
     [imgV setImage:result];
     [self.view addSubview:imgV];
}
```

I am working now to more optimize my code but for this moment I can only get the cooordintes of each image but I am not able yet to change color pixels of non common part.
Have a you an idea how should I proceed please ?

Comment: A number of problems. Gratuitous string/int conversion, archaic method names, redundant if-nesting, impossible if clauses (alpha == 255) -- this is just the first half of the first code block. Please break down your problem into smaller units and do not post so much code in one question.

Comment: It looks like you've grabbed some code off of here for finding the color of an individual pixel, and perverted it into a pretty messy algorithm.  Rendering to a single pixel size image is not an efficient way of testing lots of data.  I think you should rethink your process and start from a different approach.

Comment: I confess that my process is messy and I should break down the problem into small units as Mundi said to me:My first issue:If I have two intersected images how could I change the pixels color of the image part outside of the intersection.

Comment: I am not able to add an image to clarify the problem (I need 10 reputations)Yes img1 could be a maskImage.I try CGImageMaskCreate but here I cannot scale img2. First, I should scale and move img2.img2 has not the same size of img1.So when img2 overlaps img1 we obtain a third image.The rest of img2

Comment: the rest of img2 that doesn't overlay the img1 should be transparent

Comment: I need a method to separate between the overlap and outside the intersection.That's why I thought about points.

Comment: I wonder by the way,is there a possibility to move and scale img2 only inside img1??

Comment: I need something like that : http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/548388Capturedcran20131102185434.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than trying to do this yourself, pixel by pixel, you can use higher-level UIKit and Core Graphics functions. Consider the following final image, which is a combination of an image and a circular path which we use to (a) mask the image and (b) stroke the path:

[image: kitten with circle]

In that scenario I might:

1. Draw image at reduced alpha, so we can see it in the background.
2. Add mask, and redraw masked portion at full alpha.
3. If you need to see the outline of the mask, draw that, too.

This can be achieved with a `UIView` subview. First, define a few properties:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MaskedImageView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBezierPath *path;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;
@property (nonatomic) CGRect imageFrame;

@end
```

You can then implement a `drawRect` that does what you need:

```
#import "MaskedImageView.h"

@implementation MaskedImageView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // draw full image at 50%

    [self.image drawInRect:self.imageFrame blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.5];

    // draw clipped image at 100%

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    if (self.path) {
        CGContextAddPath(context, [self.path CGPath]);
        CGContextClip(context);
    }
    [self.image drawInRect:self.imageFrame];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    // now stroke path

    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [self.path stroke];
}

- (void)setPath:(UIBezierPath *)path
{
    _path = path;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    _image = image;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)setImageFrame:(CGRect)imageFrame
{
    _imageFrame = imageFrame;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```

You can then have your view controller create this subview, like so:

```
MaskedImageView *view = [[MaskedImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:view];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"kitten.jpeg"];
view.image = image;
view.imageFrame = CGRectMake(10, 100, image.size.width, image.size.height);
UIBezierPath *circle = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[circle addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(100,150) radius:80 startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI * 2.0 clockwise:YES];
circle.lineWidth = 3.0;
view.path = circle;
```

And if you want to render this as a `UIImage`, it's the standard technique:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, YES, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[view.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

And if you want to save that image:

```
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage);
NSString *documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *path = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.png"];
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

In the above, I'm using a path for both the mask and drawing the outline. If you really need to use a `UIImage` mask rather than path, you can do that, too, but you might need one image for the mask, and another for the outline. It depends upon the desired effect. But if the mask is circular, using a path offers greater flexibility (and is easier to implement).

---

If you use an image for the boundary (rather than a path), you can yield something like:

[image]

To do that, you might want two images (besides the cute kitten), namely, one (which I called `outlineImage`) that represents just the stroke that you'll add at the very end. In this image, I've made the transparent background green, so you can see where I have transparent pixels:

[image: stroke image]

I then have another image (which I called `clipImage`) which is the mask which is the exact same size as the `outlineImage` image above (again, green is the transparent part):

[image: mask image]

And the `drawRect` then looks something like:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // draw full image at 50%

    [self.image drawInRect:self.imageFrame blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.5];

    // draw clipped image at 100%

    if (self.clipImage) {
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, rect.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
        CGRect clipFrame = self.clipOutlineFrame;
        clipFrame.origin.y = rect.size.height - clipFrame.origin.y - clipFrame.size.height;
        CGContextClipToMask(context, clipFrame, self.clipImage.CGImage);
        CGRect imageframe = self.imageFrame;
        imageframe.origin.y = rect.size.height - imageframe.origin.y - imageframe.size.height;
        CGContextDrawImage(context, imageframe, self.image.CGImage);
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }

    // now draw outline image

    if (self.outlineImage)
        [self.outlineImage drawInRect:self.clipOutlineFrame];
}
```

This is then invoked with something like:

```
ImageMaskView *view = [[ImageMaskView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:view];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"kitten.jpeg"];
view.image = image;
view.imageFrame = CGRectMake(10, 100, image.size.width, image.size.height);

view.outlineImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loopempty.png"]; // this is the image of the stroke around the masked portion of the underlying image
view.clipImage    = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loopsolid.png"]; // this is the clipping mask (same size as outlineImage)
view.clipOutlineFrame = CGRectMake(20, 110, view.outlineImage.size.width, view.outlineImage.size.height);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.It helps me a lot.But I didn't get it.If the mask is not circular and is a specific image.How should I proceed?

Comment: @user2858284 You can obviously create complicated paths using `UIBezierPath` methods `addCurveToPoint`, `addLineToPoint`, etc. `UIBezierPath` can be used to generate very complicated paths, not just the simple circle in my first example. Or you can create an image for the mask and an image for the "stroke" as shown at the end of my modified answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.Just one thing please the "clipOutlineFrame" is it the frame of the UIImageView which holds the clipImage?

Comment: @user2858284 Yes, or because both the outline image and the clipping mask are the same size, it's the `CGRect` that defines the `frame` for both `outlineImage` and `clipImage`. I've added the code sample that invoked this image-based mask at the end of my answer.